# A routing problem in .NET 4.5,routing problem in .net 4.5 MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm setting RouteConfig.cs and I have tried 2 ways:

1.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "toControllerAction",
                url: "{controller}/{action}"
            );

            //方便隨便點的
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "",
                defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "NewsList" }
            );
        }
```

2. 

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "toControllerAction",
                url: "{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "NewsContent" }
            );

            //方便隨便點的
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "",
                defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "NewsList" }
            );
        }
```

If I give the URL: localhost:XXX
I expected that this two ways will maps to "Default".
cuz I haven't give anything.
But!
In the way 2, it maps to toControllerAction({controller}/{action}).

I have seen this two MS articles :
https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs

But I still can't understand why.

That's csproj of this project,Maybe there are some clues... :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets.1.4.10\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets.1.4.10\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets.props')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.0\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.0\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{39BBD382-9D32-404D-993F-DBA5229C4F8D}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>MVC_News2</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>MVC_News2</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
    <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
    <Use64BitIISExpress />
    <IISExpressSSLPort />
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
    <UseGlobalApplicationHostFile />
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    <DockerLaunchAction>LaunchBrowser</DockerLaunchAction>
    <DockerLaunchUrl>http://{ServiceIPAddress}</DockerLaunchUrl>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="NLog, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\NLog.5.1.3\lib\net45\NLog.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.IO.Compression" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Abstractions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Routing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
    <Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http">
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.WebRequest">
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Helpers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Optimization">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3\lib\net40\System.Web.Optimization.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Razor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WebGrease">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\WebGrease.1.6.0\lib\WebGrease.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Antlr3.Runtime">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Antlr.3.5.0.2\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="App_Start\BundleConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\FilterConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\RouteConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\NewsController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Global.asax.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Global.asax</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Models\Http.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\Parameter.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\Response.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-grid.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-grid.min.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-grid.rtl.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-grid.rtl.min.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-reboot.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-reboot.min.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-reboot.rtl.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-reboot.rtl.min.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-utilities.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-utilities.min.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-utilities.rtl.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-utilities.rtl.min.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap.min.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap.rtl.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap.rtl.min.css" />
    <Content Include="favicon.ico" />
    <Content Include="Global.asax" />
    <Content Include="Content\Site.css" />
    <Content Include="NLog.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap.rtl.min.css.map" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap.rtl.css.map" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap.min.css.map" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap.css.map" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-utilities.rtl.min.css.map" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-utilities.rtl.css.map" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-utilities.min.css.map" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-utilities.css.map" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-reboot.rtl.min.css.map" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-reboot.rtl.css.map" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-reboot.min.css.map" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-reboot.css.map" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-grid.rtl.min.css.map" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-grid.rtl.css.map" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-grid.min.css.map" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-grid.css.map" />
    <None Include="NLog.xsd">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
    <Content Include="Scripts\bootstrap.bundle.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\bootstrap.bundle.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\bootstrap.esm.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\bootstrap.esm.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\bootstrap.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\bootstrap.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\bootstrap.min.js.map" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\bootstrap.js.map" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\bootstrap.esm.min.js.map" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\bootstrap.esm.js.map" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\bootstrap.bundle.js.map" />
    <None Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile.pubxml" />
    <None Include="Scripts\jquery-3.3.1.intellisense.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery-3.3.1.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery-3.3.1.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery-3.3.1.slim.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" />
    <None Include="Scripts\jquery.validate-vsdoc.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery.validate.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery.validate.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\modernizr-2.8.3.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\vue-resource.common.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\vue-resource.es2015.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\vue-resource.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\vue-resource.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\vue.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\vue.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Web.config" />
    <Content Include="Web.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Web.Release.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Views\Web.config" />
    <Content Include="Views\_ViewStart.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Shared\Error.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\News\_ViewStart.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\News\_NewsLayout.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\News\NewsList.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\News\NewsContent.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="packages.config" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.map" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery-3.3.1.min.map" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
  <Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
  </Target>
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>50501</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>http://localhost:50501/</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>此專案參考這部電腦上所缺少的 NuGet 套件。請啟用 NuGet 套件還原，以下載該套件。如需詳細資訊，請參閱 http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105。缺少的檔案是 {0}。</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.0\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.0\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets.1.4.10\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets.1.4.10\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets.props'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets.1.4.10\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets.1.4.10\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets.targets'))" />
  </Target>
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets.1.4.10\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets.1.4.10\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets.targets')" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it.
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target> -->
</Project>
```

Comment: Why are you using .NET Framework 4.5 at all? It went out of support several years ago. The oldest supported version right now is 4.6.2

Comment: As for the question itself, registration order matters. The first route can match a request for `/` by using the defaults `News` and `NewsContent`, so that one is picked. Either put the default first or use an explicit `Home` controller instead of trying to get one controller to do everything

Comment: If you're just starting this project though, don't use ASP.NET Framework at all. .NET Framework is essentially in maintenance mode now, with all new functionality going into ASP.NET Core and .NET (Core). The container functionality you tried to use with `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets.1.4.10` works well with .NET Core and Linux containers

Comment: Thanks for your help bro.

I'm using the version  because I'm an intern.
Our corp. make us to use it so I do that haha.
(We are a financial corp.)

And as for your answer itself,Actually I can't understand.
In these two ways.
Even I exchange their order, the result is same.
I can understand the First config '/' will maps to   url: "",
But I don't know why in Sencond config '/' can maps to url: "{controller}/{action}",

Comment: Financial corporations should know about PCI-DSS requirements. I wonder how they justify using insecure runtime versions to auditors. Never mind trying to connect to stock exchanges, SWIFT etc without using TLS 1.2 or higher. As for interns, it's hard to understand because the docs, books and training materials for 10 year old versions like this are gone.

Comment: For your specific problem, don't try to use a default route that way. You've defined *two* default routes right now. One that goes to `News/NewsContent` and one that goes to `News/NewsList`. Use two separate controllers instead, one for `Home` and one for `News`. You don't need a default action for `NewsController` because the `Index()` or `Get()` action will be called if no other action is specified. You can create both a home page and a default News page by using the predefined routes